# Build systems that encourage cross-platform support?

Tags: makefile

Writing a Makefile that just works^TM in both Unix and Windows is a major pain, as the different shell interpreters (sh, command.com, cmd.exe, powershell.exe, ...) support vastly different syntaxes for basic things like `$HOME` vs `%userprofile%`, `rm -rf` vs `del /s /q`, `&&` vs `&`, and so on.

Are there build systems that help to steer configurations toward cross-platform support? For example, paths could be written Unix-style (`~/go/bin/hello`), and automatically converted to Windows paths when tasks are executed in traditional Windows environments (and maintained as Unix paths in cygwin environments!)

Or are build system users stuck with maintaining tons of messy conditional glue code? I love my CLI tools, and would prefer not to rewrite hundreds of CLI applications as Gradle / Gulp plugins.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "build systems".  Almost all Windows programs accept UNIX-style pathnames, so you can just use that virtually all the time.  Also if you install Git for Windows or straight MinGW you will have access to most basic UNIX tools including a shell, very easily. You could also switch to something like CMake, although if you have lots of specialized makefile rules that can be a big effort (it's very different, and much more restricted, than a makefile).

Comment: I attempt to have my C and C++ projects compile on \*nix and win32 using just GNU make, but without repeating all this complicated stuff over and over, so I started maintaining the whole Makefile logic in [a separate project](https://github.com/Zirias/zimk). This will probably not do what **you** need, but maybe you can get some ideas and at least reuse your own stuff in a similar way.

Comment: It is pretty easy to write a makefile which will run in UNIX and in Cygwin/MSYS, so, just drop cmd.exe and powershell support and use Cygwin.